# Derivative of $(Y-HX)^\top C(Y-HX)$ by $X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I'm trying to derive an expression for

$$\nabla_X(Y-HX)^\top C(Y-HX).$$

$Y$ and $X$ are column vectors of size $N \! \times 1$.
$H$ and $C$ are matrices of size $N \! \times N$.

I have checked [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities), but there wasn't an exactly matching identity there.

Comment: Yes, it is for transpose. I am going to use a different letter to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by opening the parenthesis.

$$ \begin{align}
(y-Hx)^\top C(y-Hx)
&= (y-Hx)^\top C(y-Hx) \\
&= (y^\top-x^\top H^\top) (Cy-CHx) \\
&= \underbrace{y^\top Cy}_{\text{scalar}} - \underbrace{y^\top CH}_{\text{row vec.}}x - x^\top \underbrace{H^\top Cy}_{\text{col. vec}} + x^\top \underbrace{H^\top CH}_{\text{matrix}}x \\
&= k - u^\top x - x^\top v + x^\top M x
\end{align} $$

Now we can apply the identities in [that Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities).

$$ \begin{align}
\implies \dfrac{d}{dx}\Big[ k - u^\top x - x^\top v + x^\top M x \Big]
&= 0 - u^\top - v^\top + x^\top(M + M^\top) \\
&= x^\top(H^\top CH + HC^\top H^\top) - H^\top C^\top y - y^\top C^\top H
\end{align} $$